# Как подключить Flash приложение к серверу

Tags: node.js, socket.io, flash

Имеется Node.js сервер с установленной библиотекой Socket.IO которая служит для организации сокетного сервера. HTML клиент не сложно сделать для такого сервера. Вопрос заключаеться в том, как подлкючиться Flash приложению к этому серверу.

Бьюсь над этой проблемой уже неделю, но без результатно.

Одно из решений я нашёл тут:
[socket.io-flash](https://github.com/sinnus/socket.io-flash-demo)
и пример как его использовать: [socket.io-flash-demo](https://github.com/sinnus/socket.io-flash-demo)

### Пример этот у меня не хочет работать, постоянно одни ошибки, дополняю нехватающей библиотекой вылетают другие ошибки, которые уже мне решить не подсилу... мне кажется я что то не так делаю. Во флеше практически не разбираюсь, ну разве что совсем базовые знания.

PS: Что не удобно в работе с github, скачиваю пример реализации а мне ещё нужно кучу библиотек устанавливать для работы этого примера. И не факт что ещё он заведётся(((

Comment: Вы не расскажете в чём проблема?

Comment: Необязательно использовать socket.io для создания сокет сервера на node.js. см [http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.4/api/net.html#net.Server][1] 

А у флеш в as 3.0 уже есть встроеные модули для сокет клиента. Таким образом, вам не нужно будет использовать "ужасный" github.


  [1]: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.4/api/net.html#net.Server